# WooCommerce - removing country field from my-account page prevents from saving address

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I sell and ship products only to one country so I don't want to display *billing_country* and *shipping_country* field to the customers. **I removed the fields** from both checkout and my-account addresses page using `unset($fields['billing_country'])`.

Checkout works fine, but after I removed those fields from my-account page, **I can't save or edit any addresses on my-account addresses page.** The page will simply refresh itself not changing anything.

This is my *functions.php* inside my theme.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
   unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
   unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
   unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
   unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);
   unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_phone']);
   return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_billing_fields' );

function custom_override_billing_fields( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['billing_country']);
  unset($fields['billing_address_2']);
        
  return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields' , 'custom_override_shipping_fields' );
function custom_override_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['shipping_country']);
  unset($fields['shipping_address_2']);
  unset($fields['shipping_phone']);
        
  return $fields;
}
```

If I comment out
`unset($fields['billing_country']);` or
`unset($fields['shipping_country']);`
everything works fine and it saves any addresses. Unsetting other fields also works. Am I doing something wrong, is there any other way to remove those fields? Thanks.

**Update:**

**WARNING - LONG STORY**

The weirdest thing happened. I made those fields hidden using css and left them set in functions.php. But then, my billing and shipping address classes got messed up!

I had those lines in my `woocommerce_billing_fields` filter hook:

```
      $fields['billing_city']['class'] = array('form-row-last');
      $fields['billing_postcode']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
      $fields['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-last');
      $fields['billing_phone']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
```

This is supposed to make those 4 fields to take 50% width of the row in the billing address form. **It worked with email and phone, but city and postcode remained 100% width**. It should replace `form-row-wide` class into `form-row-first/last` and it did so, but only for two.

So I looked into the browser and found out that somehow those two elements had `data-o_class`  attribute.

This is what I found:

```
<p class="form-row validate-required validate-postcode form-row-wide address-field" 
id="billing_postcode_field" data-priority="65" 
data-o_class="form-row form-row-first validate-required validate-postcode"></p>
```

**Element above is bugged** and has this `data-o_class` attribute which contains all the classes, however, **element below is fine** and has his classes replaced:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required validate-phone" 
id="billing_phone_field" 
data-priority="100"></p>
```

When I removed the country field with `unset($fields['billing_country'])`, the problem disappeared, but again, I couldn't save the address.

In order to fix it I had to use another filter - `woocommerce_default_address_fields` -
This is what i did in `functions.php`:

```
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields','custom_override_default_address_fields' );
  function custom_override_default_address_fields( $fields ){
    unset($fields['country']);
    return $fields;
  }
```

What it did is even better!

**It made the country fields appear again** both in checkout and on my account page, even though **it was still unset** with other filters there. But it didn't appear in the right order, **it was unstyled** and at the end of the form. So once again, I had to remove it using *css*.

But.... It fixed the classes in my billing and shipping address on my account page! I still don't know how this got my forms so messed up.

Comment: I also use ```filter hooks``` and you're doing it the right way. So what's the problem? Do you get any error when running these hooks?

Comment: @Ruvee No errors, in debug mode all clear, no idea what's the problem. I scoped through my entire theme and found no errors. So I went ahead and hid the fields in css, it doesn't satisfy me but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the same result without writing a line of code.

1. In the Wordpress admin panel go to **WooCommerce** > **Settings** > **General**.
2. In the field **Selling location(s)** select *Sell to specific countries*.
3. In the **Sell to specific countries** field, enter only the country in which you want to sell.
4. In the **Shipping location(s)** field select the option *Ship to all countries you sell to*.

[image]

In this way, on the checkout page and on the address page in your account you will see the **Billing country** and **Shipping country** fields as plain text (instead of the list of options).

**Customers will not be able to modify them.**

If you want to hide it, however, you can intervene with the css code.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the only possible solution.